# js object value change on click in localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have object, in that object there is this array:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Title1",
    "status": false
  },
  {
    "title": "Title2",
    "status": false
  }
]
```

and when I press the `a` tag, I want to change element's status from `false` to `true` and move it from "Tasks" section to "Done" section. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vvqn.png).

But in `changeStatus` function I'm getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'status' of undefined
>   at changeStatus (script.js:116)
>   at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (?new-task=Task1:1)

How could I change my element's status on the click?

```js
var tasks = {};
var element = {};
var tasksList;
var index;
Date.shortMonths = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

function short_months(dt) {
  return Date.shortMonths[dt.getMonth()];
}

function taskList() {
  var today = new Date();
  var full_date = short_months(today) + " " + today.getDate() + " " + today.getYear();
  element["title"] = document.getElementById('new-task').value;
  element["status"] = false;
  element["date"] = full_date;

  var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasksAll')) || [];
  oldItems.push(element);
  localStorage.setItem('tasksAll', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
  updateData();
}

function updateData() {
  var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("tasksAll");
  tasksList = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
  var htmlNotDone = "";
  var htmlDone = "";
  var falseCount = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < tasksList.length; index++) {
    if (tasksList[index].status === false) {
      falseCount++;
      htmlNotDone += '<div class="task-element">';
      htmlNotDone += '<div class="task-left-element"><p>' + tasksList[index].date + '</p><h4>' + tasksList[index].title + tasksList[index].status + '</h4></div>';
      htmlNotDone += '<div class="task-right-element">';
      htmlNotDone += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="changeStatus(index);"><span class="checkmark"><div class="checkmark_stem"></div><div class="checkmark_kick"></div></span></a>';
      htmlNotDone += '</div>';
      htmlNotDone += '</div>';
    } else {
      htmlDone = htmlDone + tasksList[index].title;
    }
  }
  if (htmlNotDone === "") {
    document.getElementById("task-list").innerHTML = "Nothing";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("task-list").innerHTML = htmlNotDone;
  }
  if (htmlDone === "") {
    document.getElementById("done-task-count").innerHTML = "Nothing";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("done-task-count").innerHTML = htmlDone;
  }
}

function changeStatus(index) {
  tasksList[index].status = true;
}
updateData();
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: font-Heavy;
  src: url(fonts/Aileron-Heavy.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: font-Bold;
  src: url(fonts/Aileron-Bold.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: font-Light;
  src: url(fonts/Aileron-Light.otf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: font-Regular;
  src: url(fonts/Aileron-Regular.otf);
}

body {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -10%);
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #f7f9fa;
}

.container .content {
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}

.container .content h1 {
  font-family: font-Heavy;
  color: #2f80ed;
}

.content form input[type=text] {
  font-family: font-Regular;
  padding-left: 15px;
  min-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px #e0e0e0;
}

::placeholder {
  color: #929292;
}

.content .undone-task h3,
.content .done-task h3 {
  font-family: font-Bold;
  color: #828282;
}

.content .task-element {
  border: 1px solid #e5e6e7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 18px #e5e6e7;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-height: 60px;
}

.task-element p {
  font-family: font-Light;
  color: #c5c5c5;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.task-element h4 {
  font-family: font-Light;
  color: #828282;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.task-element .task-left-element {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.task-element .task-rigth-element {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}

.checkmark {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.checkmark_stem {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 9px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 11px;
  top: 6px;
}

.checkmark_kick {
  position: absolute;
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 8px;
  top: 12px;
}

.checkmark:hover .checkmark_stem,
.checkmark:hover .checkmark_kick {
  background-color: #6fcf97;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>To-do</h1>
    <form name="taskForm" onsubmit="taskList();return false">
      <input type="text" name="new-task" id="new-task" placeholder="Task title">
      <input type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;" />
    </form>
    <div class="undone-task">
      <h3>Tasks</h3><span id="task-count"></span>
      <div id="task-list"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="done-task">
      <h3>Done</h3><span id="done-task-count"></span>
      <div id="done-task-list"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all...

You shouldn't generate HTML with JavaScript but instead use DOM queries to add/edit DOM children, for this purpose, you should learn how to use a library, like jQuery or vue.js.

Second of all, you shouldn't use onclick html attributes, but eventlisteners instead, this is usually handled by the library or framework..

Third, you're using index as a string, not as the variable, so of course it will try to use the global variable index which will be executed, way after the index loop is. So you should learn about lexical scope and variable management.

In order to solve your problem, replace `onclick="changeStatus(index);"` with `onclick="changeStatus('+index+');"` and it should work..

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I was trying to do this without any frameworks or libraries